# Trying to write output from shell command to JSON file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I am trying to write output from API request(passing through shell command) to JSON file using python.

```
import os
assignments = os.system("curl -u https://apitest.com/api/-u domain:jsdjbfkjsbdfden")
```

Getting a response in string format, How I can save this response to a JSON file

I tried with the request library in python with same domain name and api_key not sure why i am getting 404 error "{"error":"Invalid api id. Verify your subdomain parameter"}"

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
url = "https://apitest.com/api/"
headers = {"SUBDOMAIN":"domain","api_key": "jsdjbfkjsbdfden"}
authParams = HTTPBasicAuth('username@gmail.com', 'password@')
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers,auth = authParams)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

is It not easier to use a "[requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/)" libarary to make a queries ?

```
import requests
link = "" #your link

myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

r = requests.post(link, data=myobj)
r.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the requests library instead of system calls.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2')
print(r.content)
```

Writing to a file is covered in many tutorials across the internet such as [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) and has been covered extensively on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120899/python-writing-text-to-a-file/35120948) already.

Comment: I tried with request library and i got the 404 {"error":"Invalid api id. Verify your subdomain parameter"} in the response.

Comment: What domain are you trying to pass? Do you need to read more on [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685790/adding-headers-to-requests-module)?
Update your question if your code/question is changing, please.

Comment: curl https://apitest.com/api/   -u "SUBDOMAIN:API_KEY"
I am giving this command in the shell which is working fine and i am getting the response that I expected , when i tried mimic the same with request library i am getting   404 {"error":"Invalid api id. Verify your subdomain parameter"}

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a command:

```
import os
assignments = os.system("curl -u https://apitest.com/api/-u domain:jsdjbfkjsbdfden > somefile")
```

There's no real reason to use python's requests module persé except for purity, however keeping it pure python helps portability.